# Indice indefinido - Error al obtener el contenido de un campo

Tags: php

Buenas no comprendo porque me dice que no tengo definido el valor idValidar.

**Error**

> Notice: Undefined index: idValidar in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_WEB_MMR\Plataforma\PHP\Proyecto\validarPropuesta.php
>   on line 21

Yo hasta ahora cuando quería obtener el contenido de un campo siempre lo hacía mediante el name del form.

**Código html**

```
<form action="PHP/Proyecto/validarPropuesta.php" method="post">
  <h2 class="texto">Validar propuestas</h2>
  <input type="text"     name="idValidar" placeholder="Introducir id">
  <input type="submit"   value="Validar">
</form>
```

**Código php**

```
<?php

  $bd_host = "localhost"; 
  $bd_usuario = "root"; 
  $bd_password = ""; 
  $bd_base = "carrot";

  $conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password);
  mysqli_select_db($conexion,$bd_base);

  $idValidacion = $_POST['idValidar'];
  //    $idValidacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['idValidar']);

  $revision = 2;

  $consulta = "
    UPDATE propuesta
    SET revision='$revision'
    WHERE id = $idValidacion
  ";

  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

  // Liberamos y cerramos conexión.
  mysqli_free_result($resultado);
  mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: has echo un echo para ver si te esta trayendo el valor ?

Comment: ¿Dónde está el código a través del cual mandas los datos del formulario HTML al servidor? Hay que revisar si estás enviando los datos correctamente.